# How to implement RC4 encryption for python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

My code throws this error:

```
Error :     
    j = (j + S[i] + k[i % keyLen]) % 256
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
key = 242

def main():

    initializeS(key)

#Key-Scheduling algorithm used to initialize a permutation in array S
#Keylength is the number of bytes in the key it can vary from 0 - 256 bytes
def initializeS(k):

    k = str(k).encode('utf-8')
    print(k)
    keyLen = len(k)
    S = []
    j = 0

    for i in range(0, 256):
        j = (j + S[i] + k[i % keyLen]) % 256
        S[i], S[j] = S[j], S[i]
return S

main()
```

Comment: Provide your code and explain what the problem is and what you have tried, IOW a [mcve], that means sample inputs and outputs, errors and error messages.

Comment: Apologize, I have added the code now. Thank you

Comment: Hint: Use intermediate variables instead of a compound statement such as `(j + S[i] + k[i % keyLen]) % 256`. That way you will know exactly what is causing the error.

Comment: `S=[]` is incorrect. S should be initialized to [0, 1, 2, ...., 255].

Comment: The only way i remember is     S = range(256) but as Ive heard range is not supported in python 3? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S is initialized to be an empty list, so when `S[i]` executes on that line, it will fail because the list has 0 elements. Initialize S to be a list with at least 256 elements so `S[i]` is always valid for integer i between [0, 256), and you will no longer get the error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
If I do:
    `S = [0] * 256` (I will get a array full of 256 zeros)
If I do:
        `S = []
        for c in range(256):
            S.append(c)`
I will get array `S = (0,1,2,3,....255)`
Which one is correct ? 
Thank you

Comment: Both will make the code execute, but S should be a list of integers from 0 to 255, inclusive. `S = list(range(256))` is the easiest way to do that.